# How can I set up a proper has_many :through relationship with a condition, or scope, on the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Consider 3 Models, User, Group, & GroupMembership

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
end

class GroupMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  
  scope :current, -> { where(active_at: [nil, (..Time.current)], expires_at: [nil, (Time.current..)]) }
end
```

Nothing remarkable about User or Group, but GroupMembership has two DateTime columns that control whether or not the membership is current: active_at, and expires_at. My logic is that a User is a member of a group at a given point in time so long as active_at <= point_in_time < expires_at (nils are ok too).

I do not want to put a default scope on GroupMembership but I would like the has_many associations to include only joins that are current.

I have tried adding the :current scope (which is defined for GroupMembership) to the belongs_to in Group Membership, and I have tried adding the :current scope to the has_many :through of Group and User and each approach results in errors when attempting to find both a User's Groups and a Group's Users.

How do I get these relationships to work as intended?

**Edited**: I originally omitted the has_many :group_memberships in my models for this question, after adding, the question almost answered itself - the scope, which exists on the GroupMembership model, belongs on the has_many :group_memberships of the User and Group models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the scope to the has_many :group_memberships in both the User and Group models does exactly what is requested.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_memberships, -> { current }
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_memberships, -> { current }
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but you can try the following. In user or group model, you can create a new function to do the query and then just retrieve it. I am not 100% sure about the syntax but it is something along this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :group_memberships
    has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships

    def self.current
      self.joins(:group_memberships).where(active_at: [nil, (..Time.current)], expires_at: [nil, (Time.current..)])
    end
end
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
User.current
```

Comment: Sorry - please see my edits and answer. I believe my original question led you astray. After seeing your answer, I realized both my error and the correct answer.